# How to list the file with timestamp and size using input of command output

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Could you please clarify my doubt in bash shell. I am using a command to list the top 10 files

## command to display first 10 big files

```
du -ah|sort -rh|head -n 10
```

But it is listing the output as

```
size  filename
3.0 MB   test.xml
.....    .......
.....    ....... 
so on
```

I want to display the time stamps and permissions, so I am trying:

```
du -ah|sort -rh|head -n 10|xargs ls -lrt '{}'  

du -ah|sort -rh|head -n 10|awk '{print $2}'|while read i; do ls -lrt $i;done
```

But both of them is not working

Could you please advise? I want to use `du` command only

Comment: I'm confused, you say that you want to use `du` only, however in your attempts you are trying `du` with `ls`. Why don't you use only `ls`? Anyway, with `du --time` parameter you can also get the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like

```
ls -lSh | head -10 | awk '{print $5 " " $1 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9}'
```

including all subdirectories you could use find:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nrk5 | head -10
```

this is not efficient and you get the filesize not in human readable form, but it does the job:

```
    [root@myserver /etc]# find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nrk5 | head -10 2>/dev/null
    -r--r--r-- 1 root root 7259752 Jan 30 15:32 ./udev/hwdb.bin
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3703827 Jan 30 15:28 ./selinux/targeted/policy/policy.30
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3703827 Jan 30 15:28 ./selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1394978 Jan 30 15:28 ./selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.bin
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 670293 Jun  7  2013 ./services
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 384788 Apr 18  2016 ./vmware-tools/locations
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 378732 Jan 30 15:28 ./selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts
    -rw------- 1 root root 378732 Jan 30 15:28 ./selinux/targeted/active/file_contexts
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 368001 Apr 15  2016 ./selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.pre
    -r--r--r-- 1 root root 346654 Jan 30 15:26 ./pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

Comment: Thanks - Mario Keller and zumo-de-vidrio

Comment: Thanks - Mario Keller, But how to get the sub directory files list as well? - Because i dont want to use find command. is any other option in ls and du ?

Comment: Do you need only the size of the subdirectory or all files inside any subdirectory (recursive)? I think that's not that simple without find.